# Do Docker commands inside a container behave the same on different hosts OS?

Tags: docker

Running the following command inside a container built from an official Debian image (`debian:stretch-slim`) does not output the same result whether the host is macOS or Ubuntu.

```
$ grep -Rnl path/ -e 'search' | xargs grep -e 'expected'
```

Results:

```
# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
expected
expected
...

# macOS 12.4 (21F79)
path/to/file_having_search_1:expected
path/to/file_having_search_2:expected
...
```

Doesn't this defeat Docker's primary purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting the macOS host solved the issue.